# javascript cookie with 2 values, name and last visited date

Tags: javascript, cookies

What im looking for is to get a cookie to hold two values, one for the name and one for the last date they visited. It just needs to be absolutely basic/simple however i still cant figure it out.

Here is my working code but it only contains the users name, i have tried everything to get the date to work by trying to add values to this cookie, making another cookie to hold the date value but it just doesnt seem to work for me.

```
/*function getCookie(c_name)
{
    var c_value = document.cookie;
    var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
    if (c_start == -1)
    {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    }
    if (c_start == -1)
    {
        c_value = null;
    }
    else
    {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
        var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
        if (c_end == -1)
        {
            c_end = c_value.length;
        }
        c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
    }
    return c_value;
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{

    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function checkCookie()
{

    var username=getCookie("username");

    if (username!=null && username!="")
    {
        alert("Welcome again " + username + " you were last here on the "+ ledate);
    }
    else 
   {
        username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");


        if (username!=null && username!="" &&(username.substring(0,1)=='s'  ||username.substring(0,1)=='S'))
        {
             var ledate=new date();

             setCookie("username",username, 365);
             createCookie("date",ledate,365);
        }
        else
       {
             alert('error');
             location.reload();
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, as all of that code is commented out... ;-)

Comment: you might want to clean up the code a little bit so it is easier to read. first google hit gave me : http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Can you post the code where you are calling these functions to set and get the cookies?

Comment: @miah Im calling it with <body onload=checkcookie()>

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i was just messing around with diffrent stuff

Comment: Dont worry yo, i fixed it all by myself the smart way, copied all of the first cookie code, added a 1 to the end of every variable name and  just made cookie1 = a new date. All good, worked perfectly, looked awesome, smelled nice, felt sexy. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a snippet from "SAMS Teach Yourself JavaScript":

```
function createCookie(name, value, days, path, domain, secure) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    cookieString = name + "=" + escape (value);
    if (expires) cookieString += "; expires=" + expires;
    if (path) cookieString += "; path=" + escape (path);
    if (domain) cookieString += "; domain=" + escape (domain);
    if (secure) cookieString += "; secure";
    document.cookie = cookieString;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it doesnt help me... how do i add the date? Please help @Dek Dekku